# save and access data from a map inside of another map

Tags: java

I have a problem saving and accessing data from a map which is inside another map.

```
   Map<String, Integer> Mapname=new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
   Mapname.put("hello",2);
   Mapname.put("bye",3);   
   Map<String, Map<String,Integer> OutsiderMap
        = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>(); 
   String s="name"; 
   OutsiderMap.put(s,Mapname);
   for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String,Integer>> entry : OutsiderMap.entrySet())
    {
      Map<String,Integer> innermap;
        innermap=entry.getValue();


        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry2 : innermap.entrySet())
        {

        }   
    }
```

Output should be:
Should print the Outsider map not the inner map

Output now:
s={};
My output right now is the name of the string s={}. So my oustider map is empty.
Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to output?  When I put `System.out.println(entry2);` inside your innermost for-loop, I see `hello=2 bye=3`.

Comment: output: s={hello=2, bye=3}

Comment: Let me clarify.  Update your question to show the code which is generating the output.  Add comments around it indicating the expected and actual output.  Your code as posted works fine for me.

Comment: If you want to print the map, why not just `System.out.println(OutsiderMap);`?  For me it gives `{name={hello=2, bye=3}}`

Answer (score 1):

Its working with Eclipse Luna, just add the following statement in inner for loop `System.out.println(entry2);` to access `Map elements` stored in the an another `Map`.